# Re-use the app id in Play Store after losing keystore file

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, release, google-play-console

I have a little issue where I created an Android release build from my Ionic project. I've signed the app in the `platform/android/build/outputs/apk` folder, so my keystore file also was there. Then I noticed a bug, rebuild the app but I figured the folder gets cleared at each build. As a result I don't have my keystore file anymore and I'm unable to add an update to the Play Store. I've unpublished the previous version but now I'm unable to use my app id as it is used by the unpublished version.

So right now I see three options:

- Is there a way to change the app id from the unpublished app? (all related info I've read says no)
- Is there an alternative way to use the same app id? (I would not like to have differente app ids for iOS and Android)
- As a final option I could use com.mydomain.app as the iOS id and use e.g. com.mydomain.android (and I've moved my signing process to a different folder outside the Ionic project) but is there a way to keep this release-friendly (meaning, is there a way to specify platform specific app ids in Ionic config.xml or other file)

How do you guys handle stuff like this? I suppose I'm not the first random guy this has happened to.

Edit: I found that [I'm not the first random guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069674/cordova-is-it-possible-to-have-different-app-ids-for-android-and-ios-platforms) this has happened to. Which makes option 3 easier to accept if option 1 will never work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible, mentioned clearly in [the google doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en).

*If you lose your keystore, you'll need to publish a new app with a new package name.*

If you have lost you app signing key, you can not upgrade your app, that is the reason google came up with a new feature "**app signing by Google Play**", where Google keeps your signing key, but when you upload your app you need to sign your app with a key(Upload Key), then Google verifies your signature, removes the signature, and then Google re-signs the APKs with the original app signing key you provided and delivers your app to the user. Benefit of this feature is that If you lose your "Upload Key", you can request for reset it from google, and you will be provided with a new "upload key", which you will use for signing app, and Google will re-sign you app using the main key It is keeping since starting.

So I will suggest you to enrol for this feature this time, to avoid an issue in future in case you lose your singing key again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's clear now. I've created a different package name and will definitely look into Google Signing (as I turned it on, but didn't knew what it was for). For now I've signed my app from another folder outside my Ionic project :) +1A

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, this is not possible outside the scope of *App Signing by Play*.

However, **if** your app has not been installed by anyone from the Play Store (except yourself), you can request your app to be deleted, which would allow you to recreate a new app with the same package name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it was installed by a few relatives. +1

Answer (score 1):

App Id in a sense is just like a domain name, you can not have more than one as long as you are to upload the application on Google Play.

The only option for you is to create a new build with a different App id.